# Cannot connect to integration services remotely on one machine

Tags: sql-server

Something on workstation has broken the ability to get into any integrated services.  SMS and SQL (ssis) are same versions.

The error "The specified service does not exist as an installed service" comes up immediately.  This issue has been narrowed down to this workstation, same user works on other workstations.

What can we check/verify on this workstation?  TLS?  SSL?  Not firewall issue, this workstation worked at one point.

Could installing SQL 2017 DEV edition on the workstation cause this issue?

[image: Error trying to connect remotely to Integration Services]

Comment: What version of SQL Server and SSIS is the user trying to connect to? And the user is trying to connect to SSIS using SSMS? What version of SSMS is being used on this machine?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 / SSIS 2016 using SMS 2016 (13.0.16106.4).  Domain user account , same user works fine on other workstations.